# Is there a function in java to find the antilog?

Tags: java, math, natural-logarithm

I wanted to know if there is a function in java to find the antilogs or I would have to implement it myself? If so, how do I implement it?

Comment: Shouldn't `Math.pow` do this already for you?

Comment: Math.pow is not always accurate. I once raised 759 to the power 2 using Math.pow(), typecasting it to (long) and I got a wrong answer. I had to change the code to 759*759.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Math.exp(x)` returns e<sup>x</sup>.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Math.log(5)); // prints 1.6094...
    System.out.println(Math.exp(1)); // prints 2.7182...
    System.out.println(Math.exp(Math.log(5)); // prints 5.0000...
}
```

Comment: this is exactly the answer I was looking for